# Getting parent of element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm learning jQuery, so it's probably misunderstanding of some sort.

Consider javascript:

```
var controls = $("#" + val.controltovalidate);
var input = controls[0];
var parent = input.parent();                
var pos = parent.position;
```

First I'm getting list of elements with specific ID, since it is in ASP.NET I know it's just one element but I'm using jQuery and it gives me list. I also prepend with "#" to make it works. Any better way?

Second I get actual element (array at 0) `HtmlInput`
Third I want to find it's container and I'm doing `input.parent()`. This call returns NULL for me. Why? I know there is parent `P` for this `input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing `$("#" + val.controltovalidate).parent()` if you want to find immediate parent and `$("#" + val.controltovalidate).closest('p')` if you want to find the first `<p>` element in the ancestor hierarchy.

Each jQuery object is a collection so don't worry about that fact and do whatever you need to need. It will be affecting only one DOM element.

For your second question: when you access an element through index in a jQuery collection, it will return you DOM element. That's why you are getting `HTMLInputElement`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest();`

```
var parent = $(input).closest('p');
```

Comment: `HtmlInputElement doesn't support closest()` - error I'm getting

Comment: You're calling closest on an HTMLInputElement, not a jQuery object. Try wrapping as a jQuery object. $(input).closest('p').

Answer (score 0):

Try last two lines like this:

```
 var pos = $(input).parent().position();
```